# Getting 'foreign key mismatch' error when making migrations in Django model

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, foreign-keys, django-migrations

I have a model Game as such (I am defining PK field because I am populating this table through API calls that come with a gameID):

```
class Game(models.Model):
    gameId          = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, default=-1)
    season          = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    season_type     = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dateTime        = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ...
    ...
```

and a model GameOdd as such:

```
class GameOdd(models.Model):
    game                     = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sportsbook               = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    created_when             = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ...
    ...
```

The error message says "foreign key mismatch - "bets_gameodd" referencing "bets_game" " (bets is the name of the app). I am using a sqlite db, and it is empty (aside from my admin user profile). This seems like a relatively straightforward foreign key relationship, and I am defining the parent table first. I am perplexed as to why I am getting this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

https://community.simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/t/foreign-key-mismatch-error/143

According to this, delete all your migration files and SQLite file and then run `python manange.py makemigrations` again.